# Formatar apresentação de horas e minutos de variavel lida de SQL

Tags: php, html5

Estou a iniciar o PHP.
Pretendo apresentar as horas e minutos armazenadas num campo mas quando o leio  o que apresenta é algo como: `01:00:00.0000000`.

O campo SQL é do tipo time(7) e a variável para onde estou a ler é: `$row["horas_assis"]`.
Como devo fazer para só apresentar as horas e minutos?

```
<table class="lista" align="center" width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <th width="22%">Data</th>
        <th width="53%">Cliente</th>
        <th width="15%">Horas</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        $conn = ligarbd("assistec");
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM assistencias WHERE id_tec=$id_tec";
        $result = odbc_exec($conn,$SQL);

        while($row = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><h7><?=$row["data"]?></h7></td>
        <td><?=$row["id_cli"]?></td>
        **<td><?=$row["horas_assis"]?></td>**
        <td>
            <a href="assistencias.php?id=<?=$row['id_tipo']?>&tipo=0"><img src="img/alterar_tec.png" alt="Editar"></a>
            <a href="assistencias.php?id=<?=$row['id_tipo']?>&tipo=1"><img src="img/apag_tec.png" alt="Apagar"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
    odbc_close();
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar a função `date()` com `strtotime()` para formatar a hora corretamente, também é possível fazer isso direto pelo sql.

PHP

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($row["horas_assis"]));
```

SQL

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('01:00:00.0000000', '%H:%i:%s')
```

[Parâmetros da função date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[Parâmetros da função TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu a situação.